# MS ACCESS параллельная работа

Tags: sql, access, vba, office

Можно ли заставить MS Access работать параллельно? К примеру я замечал, что если врубить восстановление базы, то новую базу открыть нельзя, пока восстановление первой не закончится...

Такое впечатление, что Access работает в 1 поток.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые операции требуют монопольного доступа. Обычная работа, связанная с выполнением запросов, без изменения схемы данных - без проблем.

Хочется большего - MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Firebird и прочая, прочая, прочая.

Comment: Монопольного доступа к чему? Я пытаюсь разные базы открыть. Если одна база восстанавливается, то абсолютно другую бд я открыть не могу. Попросту ничего не происходит.

Comment: Второй экземпляр Access тоже блокируется, если его отдельно запустить?

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный, Если один процесс не отвечает, то ещё один не запустить в этом же сеансе Windows

Answer (score 0):

Access - это приложение. Можно открыть несколько таких приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше тоже сталкивался с такой неприятностью при работе MS ACCESS. Если один запущенный процесс занят выполнением длительной операции, то открыть новый не удается до окончания операции.
Но, как оказалось - не удаётся открыть через проводник Windows, если запустить новый экземпляр самого приложения через Пуск или другим способом без участия explorer.exe, то он откроется сразу. Останется через его меню найти файл базы данных и открыть.